# Jquery datatable jeditable, editing field resets pagination

Tags: jquery, datatables, jeditable

I'm using jquery datatables with the jeditable plugin.
These are the options of my datatable

```
options = {
        "bServerSide" : true,
        "sAjaxSource" : "/javaServlet",
        "bProcessing" : true,
        "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
        "bJQueryUI" : true
    };
```

and My jeditable column options

```
    options = {
        placeholder : '',
        fnOnCellUpdated : function(sStatus, sValue,
                settings) {
            recordUpdated();
        }
};
```

The problem is when i edit a value in the 4th page for example, the datatable updates and reloads and sends me back to the first page.

When checking the network, "javaServlet" is being called again after the update is done

How can I fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution I found [here](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/4470/pagination-is-reset-when-using-a-jeditable/p1) (by [fabatt](http://datatables.net/forums/profile/18642/fabatt) and [allan](http://datatables.net/forums/profile/1/allan)):

"In the file jquery.dataTables.editable.js you can find the `fnUpdate` command in the function `_fnApplyEditable`. Add on both a false parameter and deactivate the invokement of `_fnSetDisplayStart();`"